How to get custom fields that are passed during payment_link generation in Stripe webhook inside Metadata while generating payment_intent
I have created an API route to generate payment link in my project
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export async function POST(req) {
    try {
        const body = await req.json();
        const { invoiceId, amount, currency, invoiceNumber, stripeAccountId } = body;

        const product = await stripe.products.create({
            name: `Invoice #${invoiceNumber}`
        }, {
            stripeAccount: stripeAccountId
        });

        const price = await stripe.prices.create({
            product: product.id,
            unit_amount: currency === "JPY" ? amount : amount * 100,
            currency: currency
        }, {
            stripeAccount: stripeAccountId // Specify the connected account ID
        });

        const paymentLink = await stripe.paymentLinks.create({
            line_items: [
                {
                    price: price.id,
                    quantity: 1,
                },
            ],
            metadata: {
                invoiceId: invoiceId // Add the invoice number here
            }
        }, {
            stripeAccount: stripeAccountId // Specify the connected account ID
        });

        return new Response(JSON.stringify({
            success: true,
            message: "Payment link generated successfully",
            url: paymentLink.url
        }), {
            status: 200,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({
            success: false,
            message: error.message
        }), {
            status: 500,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
    }
}

Now this is successfully creating payment in the Stripe connected account with Metadata that I passed,
After that to capture the payment status, I created a webhook in main Stripe account
Here's code to that api route
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { stripe } from '@/utils/stripeAuth';

export async function POST(req) {
    let rawBody;

    try {
        // Read raw body as a string
        rawBody = await req.text();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error reading raw body:', err);
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: false,
            message: `Failed to read request body: ${err.message}`,
        }, {
            status: 400,
        });
    }

    const sig = req.headers.get('stripe-signature');

    if (!sig) {
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'No stripe-signature header value was provided.',
        }, {
            status: 400,
        });
    }

    let event;

    try {
        // Convert the raw body string to a buffer with the correct encoding
        const buf = Buffer.from(rawBody, 'utf8');

        // Verify the event by constructing it using the raw body buffer and the signature
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf, sig, process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Webhook signature verification failed:', err);
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: false,
            message: `Webhook Error: ${err.message}`,
        }, {
            status: 400,
        });
    }

    let paymentIntent;

    // Handle the event
    switch (event.type) {
        case 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
            paymentIntent = event.data.object;
            // console.log(`PaymentIntent for ${paymentIntent.amount} failed.`);
            break;
        case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
            paymentIntent = event.data.object;
            const invoiceId = paymentIntent.metadata.invoiceId;
            // console.log(`PaymentIntent for ${paymentIntent.amount} succeeded.`);
            break;
        default:
            console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
    }

    return NextResponse.json({
        success: true,
        message: paymentIntent,
    }, {
        status: 200,
    });
}

Now inside paymentIntent metadata is coming empty
"metadata": {
},
I want invoiceId in metadata to update the payment status for invoice I created from my system
Please help me solve this issue
I checked the request body of the webhook in Stripe main account and there also I found that that metadata is empty.
I also checked /v1/payment_links API route, in that APIs request and response body metadata has invoiceId field present
I want help from fellow developers that how to pass metadata from payment_link on Stripe connected account to Webhook on main Stripe account.

Payment Link is a re-usable payment URL, i.e. customer can make payment multiple times on the same URL, and the metadata will be the same across all the payments using the payment link.
For one-time payment URL, I'd recommend using Checkout Session. A Checkout Session supports ad-hoc price using price_data (you don't need to pre-create the price object first).
Stripe doesn't populate from one object to another, i.e. metadata set in the Payment Link creation request doesn't get populated to Payment Intent object. To have metadata shown at the Payment Intent, I'd suggest also setting payment_intent_data.metadata in the request when creating an one-time Checkout Session or reusable Payment Link.
Reference: https://docs.stripe.com/metadata#set-indirectly

Thank you for the response, I'll try Checkout Session and let you know

I have implemented payment_intent_data.metadata and it served my purpose, thank you very much for the help.
